# get property of array as new array c#

Tags: c#, arrays, sub-array

Suppose I have a class like the following:

```
class Book
{
    public int id;
    public string title;
}
```

And somewhere later I have an array `Book[] books` and now want an array of the titles `string[] titles = {books[0].title, books[1].title, ..., books[n].title}`. Is there an easier way than looping over the `books` array? Something like

```
string[] titles = books.getProperty(title)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally, you would use [Linq](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/introduction-to-linq-queries) methods to manipulate collections, for example ([`Select`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netframework-4.8) & [`ToArray`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.toarray?view=netframework-4.8)):

```
var titles = books.Select(x => x.title).ToArray();
```

However, since this is an array and you an array as a result, you can also use some static methods on the `Array` type ([`ConvertAll`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.convertall?view=netframework-4.8)):

```
var titles = Array.ConvertAll(books, x => x.title);
```